# How to export C# methods?

Tags: c#, python, methods, export, python.net

How can we export C# methods?

I have a dll and I want to use its methods in the Python language with the ctypes module.
Because I need to use the ctypes module, I need to export the C# methods for them to be visible in Python.

So, how can I export the C# methods (like they do in C++)?

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, this _is_ possible. See [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20221220141336/http://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports).

Comment: python.net allows bi-directional interop between Python and .NET using Python C-API and .NET Pinvoke and Unmanaged Exports, mentioned below. So all the hard pieces are written for you! http://pythonnet.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

With the normal Python implementation ("CPython"), you can't, at least not directly.

You could write native C wrappers around our C# methods using [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI), and call these wrappers from Python.

Or, you could try [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/). This lets you run Python code and call code in any .Net language, including C#.

Comment: I want to use Python itself and not an extra implementation of it like IronPython.

Answer (score 1):

The "normal" way of exposing .NET/C# objects to unmanaged code (like Python) is to create a COM-callable wrapper for the C# DLL (.NET assembly), and call that using Python's COM/OLE support.  To create the COM-callable wrapper, use the `tlbexp` and/or `regasm` command-line utilities.

Obviously, however, this does not provide a C/DLL-style API.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible.  If you need DLL exports you'll need to use the C++/CLI language.  For example:

```
public ref class Class1 {
public:
  static int add(int a, int b) {
      return a + b;
  }
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 
int add(int a, int b) {
  return Class1::add(a, b);
}
```

The class can be written in C# as well.  The C++/CLI compiler emits a special thunk for the export that ensures that the CLR is loaded and execution switches to managed mode.  This is not exactly fast.

Writing [ComVisible(true)] code in C# is another possibility.

Comment: Actually, it is possible. See my answer.

Comment: Meh, neither the article nor the downloadable source code explains how it works.  I'll wait for confirmation from the OP.

Comment: I had to build a wrapper c++ dll (of the c# dll) to properly use the ctypes module!

Comment: And there we have it.

Comment: @HansPassant you seem to downplay Unmanaged Exports in all reverse pinvoke threads on SO. But does C++/CLI have a "downloadable source code"? When was the last time C++ features were added to C++/CLI? UE is licensed MIT and ILSPY is pretty good at providing C# code for it.

Comment: I certainly do, it is the worst possible solution. It is not like it can't work, it is because nobody can ever figure out what to do what the code fails. Not the user of the code either, there is no reasonable diagnostic. Bam, dead. Why the author doesn't open-source his code so it can be improved is very mysterious as well.   Well, he doesn't have to, just like he doesn't have to provide support.

Comment: @HansPassant the unmanaged exports code is now actively maintained on github:
https://github.com/3F/DllExport