# howto call c# (mono , .net) methods, delegates from native c

Tags: c#, c, mono, compilation, native

is it possible to call c# methods written in managed code (maybe in a class or a library) from a native c code (and how)?

thx

edit: with "c#" i mostly refer to mono or even portable.net and the OS is Linux

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to export c# methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082159/how-to-export-c-methods)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your C code can define functions to register callbacks. The C# code can P/Invoke these functions, and pass managed delegates as arguments. The marshalling code will transparently transform these to C function pointers.

Alternatively, approaching it from the C side, you can use the Mono embedding API to load assemblies, look up MonoMethods, and invoke them.

Using the embedding API is much more complicated. If your entry point is in C, you'll have to use the embedding API, but it's likely easier to simply write a managed method to do the callback registration and any other managed setup, then you only have to load and invoke that single method from C code.

Comment: The entry points sometimes will be in C maybe assembler too. Well i will try to go after these http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono instructions. If you have any good other tutorials you can tell me.

Answer (score 3):

There's an [Overview of Managed/Unmanaged Code Interoperability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973872.aspx) on the MSDN site that might shed some light for you. An excerpt below:

> **Directly Accessing a Managed API**
>
> If an unmanaged client is written in
>   C++, it can be compiled with the
>   Visual Studio .NET C++ compiler as a
>   "mixed mode image." After this is
>   done, the unmanaged client can
>   directly access any managed API.
>   However, some coding rules do apply to
>   accessing managed objects from
>   unmanaged code; check the C++
>   documentation for more details.
>
> Direct access is the preferred option
>   since it does not require any special
>   consideration from managed API
>   developers. They can design their
>   managed API according to managed API
>   design guidelines (DG) and be
>   confident that the API will still be
>   accessible to unmanaged callers.
>
> **Exposing a Managed API as a COM API**
>
> Every public managed class can be
>   exposed to unmanaged clients through
>   COM interop. This process is very easy
>   to implement, because the COM interop
>   layer takes care of all the COM
>   plumbing. Thus, for example, every
>   managed class appears to implement
>   IUnknown, IDispatch,
>   ISupportErrorInfo, and a few other
>   standard COM interfaces.
>
> Despite the fact that exposing managed
>   APIs as COM APIs is easy, managed and
>   COM object models are very different.
>   Therefore, exposing managed API to COM
>   should always be an explicit design
>   decision. Some features available in
>   the managed world have no equivalent
>   in the COM world and will not be
>   usable from COM clients. Because of
>   this, there is often tension between
>   managed API design guidelines (DG) and
>   compatibility with COM.
>
> If COM clients are important, write
>   your managed API according to the
>   managed API design guidelines, and
>   then write a thin COM-friendly managed
>   wrapper around your managed API that
>   will be exposed to COM.
>
> **Exposing a Managed API as a Flat API**
>
> Sometimes unmanaged clients cannot use
>   COM. For example, they might already
>   be written to use flat APIs and cannot
>   be changed or recompiled. C++ is the
>   only high-level language that allows
>   you to expose managed APIs as flat
>   APIs. Doing this is not as
>   straightforward as exposing a managed
>   API as a COM API. It is a very
>   advanced technique that requires
>   advanced knowledge of C++ interop and
>   the differences between the managed
>   and unmanaged worlds.
>
> Expose your managed API as a flat API
>   only if absolutely necessary. If you
>   have no choice, be sure to check the
>   C++ documentation and be fully aware
>   of all the limitations.

Comment: C++/CLI only works on Windows, and the presence of the "mono" tag indicates cross-platform support is probably desirably.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.  To call C# function from C one uses [DllExport] attribute (opposite of P/Invoke DllImport).
https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports