# Calling Mono Assemblies from Java

Tags: java, linux, mono, interop

I have a large text proofing framework written in C# and I want to write a OpenOffice extension that uses this set of libraries. My prefered language for doing so is Java. Hence, I need a method to access .NET assemblies from Java (both in Windows and **Linux**). Is there a way to call Mono assemblies from Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IKVM should allow you to do what you want but I must admit that I haven't done this myslef.

Here's a link to their project: http://www.ikvm.net/

And a simple java program that calls the .NET API

```
import cli.System.IO.*;

public class ShowDir{

   public static void main(String[] args){
       String[] files = Directory.GetFiles("."); //.NET System.IO
       for(String file : files){
           System.out.println(file);
       }
   }
}
```

[More useful info](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=Tutorial).

Comment: Thanks, it can solve the java-mono interoperability in general, but ikvm is not a valid JRE to be used with openoffice.org (or it is but I cannot get it to work)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a duplicate of: [howto call c# (mono , .net) methods, delegates from native c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256139/howto-call-c-sharp-mono-net-methods-delegates-from-native-c)

You can use JNI to execute some native c code to get in through that API.