# Is it possible to load .net dll from Lua code?

Tags: .net, dll, lua

I know how to load a C library from Lua:

```
 -- Lua
 require("your_dll_name");

 // C
 extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) LUALIB_API int luaopen_your_dll_name(lua_State *L) {...}
```

But is it possible to load .net libraries from Lua?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082159/how-to-export-c-methods

Answer (score 2):

> [LuaInterface](http://luaforge.net/projects/luainterface/) is a library for integration between the Lua language and Microsoft .NET platform's Common Language Runtime (CLR). Lua scripts can use it to instantiate CLR objects, access properties, call methods, and even handle events with Lua functions.

Comment: Thank you for the link. It seems software which uses Lua scripts should support LuaInterface in order to load .net dll from Lua.