# How to export dll functions?

Tags: c#

I made a dll in c# but i need to export the functions.

Is there any way of doing it in c# or other ideas of doing the same thing?

Comment: With a view to doing what? Using in a C++ application? VB? Something else?

Comment: Please explain what you would like them to be imported into. That is a key point of information

Comment: Yes , a c++ application will call / use the functions

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to export c# methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082159/how-to-export-c-sharp-methods)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any [`public`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzh058ae%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) classes and thier `public` members will be visible by adding an assembly reference to your C# Assembly (DLL).

So if in your assembly you have:

```
public class Helper
{
     public static Foo() { } //Visible.
     private static Bar() { } //Not Visible.
     internal static FooBar() { } //Not Visible.
     protected static Wibble() { } //Visible when created a class derived from Helper.
}

private class HiddenHelper //Not Visible
{
     public static Foo() { } //Not Visible.
     private static Bar() { } //Not Visible.
     //etc. Not Visible
}
```

Anything less than public will be hidden.

---

Unless this is to be called by something outside .Net. Then you will have to [use COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645738%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Only if they are not marked as `internal` ;) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: @Dave Even `public` is entirely hidden when `static` is missing. ;) Good one anyway!

Comment: @bonCodigo are you doing `Helper.Foo();` instead of `var h = new Helper; h.Something();` (where Something is `public void Something() { }` ?

Comment: You actually answered the OP with your solution. What I was saying, .dll is to me a class full of static functions...since mostly we only need to consume what's exposed and job's done. I did face issues in the beggining when .dll were created with mere public functions in a simple public class and those methods weren't static - so the functions weren't visible at all. However I haven't encountered a time that .dll was instantiated...As for now, I was drawn to your solution for interop tag, given I have a task to use .Net .dll in a Microsoft Navision 2013 code.